# Google voice recognition to search text issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

the default text is enter your keywords ,where i click the google voice regonition and said facebook api .then the facebook api is printed along with default text like this .enter your text facebook api ... google chrome only works

```
 <form method="GET" name="search" action="index2.php"> 
   <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px"><tr><td>
   <input type="text" name="q" value="Enter your keywords here" 
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your keywords here') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if      (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your keywords here';}"
x-webkit-speech style="left:9px;top:4px;position:relative;background-   color:#fafafa;border:1px solid;color:#333;font-size:1.4em;width:400px;height:28px"; />
</td><td><input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" id="searchbutton">
</td></tr></table></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because webkit speech event doesn't trigger input's `focus` event. You should listen to `webkitspeechchange` event. Like this:

```
onwebkitspeechchange = "this.value = this.value.replace('Enter your keywords here','')";
```